# NullPointerException while loading extension in linux

Tags: java, linux, fedora, apache-zookeeper, druid

Hi I am new to [Druid](http://druid.io/) and [zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) and was trying out their basic sort of tut [here](http://druid.io/docs/0.7.3/Tutorial:-A-First-Look-at-Druid.html).

What I did is just to run two commands. The first one is to run the zookeeper:

```
[root@ingester bin]# source zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... [1]+  Exit 1                  nohup "$JAVA" "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=${ZOO_LOG_DIR}" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=${ZOO_LOG4J_PROP}" -cp "$CLASSPATH" $JVMFLAGS $ZOOMAIN "$ZOOCFG" > "$_ZOO_DAEMON_OUT" 2>&1 < /dev/null
STARTED
```

So the zookeeper seems to have started quite well.

The second command is to run example that comes built-in with druid's tarball. And this is where I am getting into trouble.

```
1:     [root@ingester druid-0.7.1.1]# source run_example_server.sh 
2:     This will run a stand-alone version of Druid
3:     Please specify an example by its number.
4:     Examples available:
5:     1 - wikipedia/wikipedia_realtime.spec - No Description
6:     2 - twitter/twitter_realtime.spec - No Description
7:     [1] > 1
8:  
9:     Running command:
10:     ++ java -Xmx512m -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Ddruid.realtime.specFile=/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/examples/wikipedia/wikipedia_realtime.spec -classpath '/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/../config/realtime:/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/examples/wikipedia:/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/config/_common:/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/config/realtime:/opt/druid-0.7.1.1/lib/*' io.druid.cli.Main example realtime
11:     2015-06-15T11:53:01,737 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.PropertiesModule - Loading properties from common.runtime.properties
12:     2015-06-15T11:53:01,740 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.PropertiesModule - Loading properties from runtime.properties
13:     Jun 15, 2015 11:53:01 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
14:     INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
15:     2015-06-15T11:53:02,202 INFO [main] io.druid.guice.JsonConfigurator - Loaded class[class io.druid.guice.ExtensionsConfig] from props[druid.extensions.] as [ExtensionsConfig{searchCurrentClassloader=true, coordinates=[io.druid.extensions:druid-examples, io.druid.extensions:druid-kafka-eight, io.druid.extensions:mysql-metadata-storage], defaultVersion='0.7.1.1', localRepository='/root/.m2/repository', remoteRepositories=[https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, https://metamx.artifactoryonline.com/metamx/pub-libs-releases-local]}]
16:     2015-06-15T11:53:02,317 INFO [main] io.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension[io.druid.extensions:druid-examples] for class[io.druid.cli.CliCommandCreator]
17:     2015-06-15T11:54:16,199 ERROR [main] io.druid.initialization.Initialization - Unable to resolve artifacts for [io.druid.extensions:druid-examples:jar:0.7.1.1 (runtime) -> [] < [ (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases+snapshots),  (https://metamx.artifactoryonline.com/metamx/pub-libs-releases-local, releases+snapshots)]].
18:     java.lang.NullPointerException
19:     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:361) ~[aether-impl-0.9.0.M2.jar:?]
20:     at io.tesla.aether.internal.DefaultTeslaAether.resolveArtifacts(DefaultTeslaAether.java:289) ~[tesla-aether-0.0.5.jar:0.0.5]
21:     at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.getClassLoaderForCoordinates(Initialization.java:214) [druid-server-0.7.1.1.jar:0.7.1.1]
22:     at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.getFromExtensions(Initialization.java:141) [druid-server-0.7.1.1.jar:0.7.1.1]
23:     at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:76) [druid-services-0.7.1.1.jar:0.7.1.1]
24:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
25:     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:361)
26:     at io.tesla.aether.internal.DefaultTeslaAether.resolveArtifacts(DefaultTeslaAether.java:289)
27:     at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.getClassLoaderForCoordinates(Initialization.java:214)
28:     at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.getFromExtensions(Initialization.java:141)
29:     at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Is it trying to download something online, since it says `Loading extension[io.druid.extensions:druid-examples] for class[io.druid.cli.CliCommandCreator]` on line 16. I am behind corporate firewall, so something might be getting blocked if any download attempt is done. Also it says `NullPointerException` on line 18. Whats the exact problem?

I am really not able to cleanly run this example. Also I am on Fedora 20, with zookeeper 3.4.6 and druid 0.7.1.1.

Comment: It looks like it could not reach any of the maven repo you mentioned. From the server just ping/or telnet to the maven repo URLs and check the connectivity

Comment: @luck wearer, do you mean to try `ping repo1.maven.org`? it says unknown host, can you check if these are reachable from you?

Comment: Yes it is reachable.. so that seems to be the problem .. if not echo port, at least port 80 to those servers should be opened for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having some problems downloading the dependencies. You can take a look at: http://druid.io/docs/latest/operations/including-extensions.html about putting jars in the classpath.

FWIW, you will get a faster response by posting questions here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/druid-user

Comment: hey thanks for pointing to this precise stuff, just wondering what does that 3rd point means: *Bundle up the local repository along with your other Druid stuff into whatever you use for a deployable artifact*

To be specific, I realized that the error was due to kafka and examples extension. So I removed them and the error disappered. 

However whats this 3rd point? Actually will like to have some example commands also explaining how to use `tools pull-deps` and bundle them. May be its usual linux stuff, not druid specific stuff. Any link explaining the same? I am on Fedora 20.